# Javascript / jQuery with localStorage API not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to use the localStorage API to grab an email value when the user submits a form and then populate another form field later.

I tried using vanilla javascript first:

```
window.onload = function() {

  // Check for LocalStorage support.
  if (localStorage) {

    // Add an event listener for form submissions
    document.getElementById('searchBooking').addEventListener('submit', function() {
      // Get the value of the email field.
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

      // Save the email in localStorage.
      localStorage.setItem('email', email);
    });

  }  

  // Retrieve the users email.
   var email = localStorage.getItem('email');

   if (email != "undefined" || email != "null") {
     document.getElementById('guestEmail').innerHTML = email;
   } else {
     document.getElementById('guestEmail').innerHTML = "";
   }

}
```

But got this error message in the browser console on line 21:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Then I tried with this jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  // Check for LocalStorage support.
  if (localStorage) {
    // Add an event listener for form submissions
    $('#searchBooking').on('submit', function() {
      // Get the value of the email field.
      var email = $('#email').value;
      // Save the name in localStorage.
      localStorage.setItem('#email', email);
  });
  }

  var email = localStorage.getItem('#email');
  if (email != "undefined" || email != "null") {
    $('#guestEmail').html = email;
  }
   else {
    $('#guestEmail').html = "";
    }
});
```

I didn't get an error message but nothing worked.

Sorry, I am very new to Javascript and don't use it very often, but I really need to save this value and repopulate it in another form.

Comment: do u have an element named `guestEmail` in your page?

Comment: make sure you have an element with id "guestEmail"

Comment: the way you're setting the value in jquery is also wrong. it should be `$('#guestEmail').html('')` or `$('#guestEmail').html(email)`

Comment: yes I do have a form field with id guestEmail - is that enough? I was using this tutorial: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/storing-data-on-the-client-with-localstorage

Comment: can you show us the html?

Comment: Quick note: You probably want to change `if (email != "undefined" || email != "null")` to `if (email != undefined && email != null)` or `if (email)` to be even more concise.

Comment: `$('#email').value` should be `$('#email').val()` (similar to how `$('#guestEmail').html = "..."` should be `$('#guestEmail').html("...")`)

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rd7s5h6j/

Comment: Sure @Sushil, in the gist I show both where the email value needs to be grabbed (form1), and where it needs to inputted (form2) : https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/9884689308dc6b98f0de

Comment: take a look at the jsfiddle and try to update your code. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: after having a look at your code, i see that `searchBooking` is the id of the div and you've written `$('#searchBooking').on('submit', function() {` in your jquery code. it will not work since its not a button or form. you need to write `$('form').on('submit', function(){ //your code here });`

Comment: thanks @Sushil but how will it know if it is the right form, don't I need to do more? I just tried putting my html code into jsfiddle and running it with your new js with form and it didn't work

Comment: you can name the form or have an id to it and instead of using `$('form')`  you can use `$('#formID')` where `formID` is the id of the form

Comment: did it work for you @daneasterman?

Comment: No, my html is generated with Rails so I had to look up how you set the id on a form. I've done this now, but I need to try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84601/discussion-between-sushil-and-daneasterman).

Comment: @daneasterman I've posted my solution. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after looking at your **[gist](https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/9884689308dc6b98f0de)** link, I found that `guestEmail` is a `textbox` on your page so the `innerHTML` is not going to work here. also the jquery implementation for both `.value` and `.html` is not correct.

you need to update your jquery as follows

```
$(function() {
    // Check for LocalStorage support. 
    if (localStorage) {
        // Add an event listener for form submissions 

        $('form').on('submit', function() {
            // Get the value of the email field. 
            var email = $('#email').val();
            // Save the name in localStorage. 
            localStorage.setItem('#email', email);
            $('#guestEmail').html(email);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('#email'));
        });
    }

    var emailLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('#email');
    console.log(emailLocalStorage);

    if (typeof emailLocalStorage != "undefined" && emailLocalStorage != "null") {
        $('#guestEmail').val(emailLocalStorage);
        console.log(emailLocalStorage)
    } else {
        $('#guestEmail').val("");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sushil this will be extremely useful for my app, I'm reusing the code to capture other pieces of data now, not just email. Couldn't have done it without your help!

Comment: you're most welcome :) glad was able to help you out. let me know if you need any help.